# Is it possible to find a monogenic field, which has a non monogenic subfield?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be a monogenic field, that is $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$. Let $K \subset L$ be a subfield, does it necessarily have this monogenic property? Do we have necessarily $\mathcal{O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\beta]$?

My attempt: We can assume that $L=\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ and $\mathcal{O}_L=\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ and $K=\mathbb{Q}[\beta]$, where $\beta=g(\alpha)$ and $g$ is a monic polynomial and both of them are algebraic integers. I want to try to show $\mathbb{Q}[\beta] \cap \mathbb{Z}[\alpha] \subseteq  \mathbb{Z}[\beta]$. But I can not, and I have some doubt if this is true or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easy to find $K$ first and $L \supset K$ later. According to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251200/example-of-galois-non-monogenic-number-field) answer, $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{17}, \sqrt{41})$ is not monogenic. However, since $K/\mathbb{Q}$ is abelian, by Kronecker-Weber theorem, it is contained in some cyclotimic field $L = \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{n})$ (I think $n = 17 \times 41$ or $n = 4 \times 17 \times 41$ would work, but I'm not sure), [which is monogenic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17289/quick-proof-of-the-fact-that-the-ring-of-integers-of-mathbb-q-zeta-n-is-m).

Comment: Thanks, also $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7}, \sqrt{10})$ works too. It is not monogenic and since it is abelian, again by Kronecker Weber......