# Primitive Elements and Bases of Fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-numbers

Good people!

I'm trying to prove a certain something, and I've reached a point where the whole thing will be complete if I can just prove the following lemma, which I'm actually not entirely certain is true. Hence I'm appealing to you for help!

**Proposition:**

Let $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ be an algebraic extension of the field of rational numbers, and let this extension be of degree $n$. Then, there necessarily exists a primitive element $\beta \in \mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ such that all algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ may be expressed in the form
$$
v_0 + v_1 \beta + v_2 \beta^2 + \dots + v_{n-1} \beta^{n-1} ,
$$
**where the $v_i$'s are all integers.**

Is this true? If so, how does one go about proving it?

Is this false? If so, what would be a neat counterexample?

As always, thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2251200/example-of-galois-non-monogenic-number-field). Such number fields are called "non-monogenic", so you can't write all elements in the ring of integers as $v_0 + v_1 \beta + v_2 \beta^2 + \dots + v_{n-1} \beta^{n-1}.$ Actually, there are better duplicates, see below.

Comment: Thanks @DietrichBurde! This looks very much like what I'm after, but the terminology is a tad too, shall we say, beyond me. You wouldn't mind translating the pertinent sentences for someone who isn't too well-wandered in Galois theory to show how it relates to my case?

Comment: AH! Monogenic simply means that very thing about all algebraic integers in $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ being expressible in the form $v_0 + v_1 \beta + \dots$. I see! The proposition does NOT hold true! Annoying, but whatchagonnado?

Thanks again! :)